# Accessing Server Instance from Other PHP classes

Tags: php, websocket, client, server, phpwebsocket

I am developing a blog application in php where I am using web sockets to achieve real time or close to real time updating of posts.

I am able to connect to socket and the messages that I send from the client is received by the server and vice verse.

My Problem is how do I access the socket instance outside this file. I mean on other php files where I do all the logic.

Comment: I don't know how to work with websocket in PHP but it seems like basic inheritence is what you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried but it is still not working.